# Huge file input/output

Tags: linux, memory, operating-systems

My question is a bit general, but the application is very practical. I wonder, how does system (Linux in particular, but general mechanisms are interesting too) handles reading/writing of huge (larger than available RAM) files.

For example, if I try to read file "foo.txt" with size 40 GB, in which ways can it be read? How will the system present it then?

Another example: we're writing to a file. It becomes bigger and biggger. At some point it takes more space that we have left in our RAM. What the system will do? (swap pages with file? Which ones?)

*Here is the motivation behind this questions*: I need to write a database to an xml file (in some specific way). So if the db is, say 20 GB, these questions arise.

Comment: If I recall, the file streams into a memory buffer, when that buffer gets full it writes it to the disk and then rinses and repeats until EOF.